# Return hours in current day

Tags: php, time

I have this function:

```
$starDate  = "2018-03-10";
$endDate = "2018-03-15";

private static function getDefaultEmptyArray($starDate,$endDate)
{
        $returnArray=array();
        $begin = new DateTime( $starDate );
        $end = new DateTime( $endDate );
        $end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
        $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

        foreach ($period as $dt) {

            $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d")]['clicks'] = 0;
            $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d")]['payout'] = 0;
            $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d")]['sales'] = 0;

        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
```

That is return me an array like this:

```
["2018-03-10"]=>
  {
    ["clicks"]=>"0"
    ["payout"]=>"0"
    ["sales"]=>"0"
  }

......

["2018-03-15"]=>
  {
    ["clicks"]=>"0"
    ["payout"]=>"0"
    ["sales"]=>"0"
  }
```

Is return me an range date array between 2018-03-10 and 2018-03-15.

My question is, how I can update this function to return me hours of current day like 00AM 01AM 02AM ...... 22PM, 23PM  in array like on days range.

Comment: Well one would have to apply ones mind to writing a few extra lines of code

Comment: Once you have tried that, if you get issues with YOUR code come on back and ask for help. We will be here and more than willing to help fixing your code, **but we dont write it for you**

Comment: It is also a good idea to tell us how and where you want this new data to be placed in your array

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: From the headline alone I'd say the answer is 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding intervals of 1 day to your start date, add intervalls of one hour to them:

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour');
```

After that, you only have to output the current time in your loop:

```
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d HA")]['clicks'] = 0;
    $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d HA")]['payout'] = 0;
    $returnArray[$dt->format("Y-m-d HA")]['sales'] = 0;
}
```